# Multiple scripts causing linking issues? Javascript, CSS, HTML, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having problems with images and fonts not linking properly, I'm wondering if it has something to do with having multiple scripts on one page? Some of the scripts are embedded into the html and others are linked externally. Here are the problems:

- There is one image that isn't linking (buttons for a slideshow), in all browsers.
- Fonts aren't working in Firefox and Opera, they were working before (the fonts are self-hosted using a kit from a font company).

You can see the page here. http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/146-madison.php

Thanks for your help.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100">
<title>Boris Kholodov &#183; 146 Madison &#183; Toronto, Canada</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../design.css">

</head>

<body bgcolor="#fafbff">


<?php include('../navigation.html');?> 



<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div id="page-wrap">




<div id="container" >
    <ul>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/1.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/2.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/3.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/4.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/5.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/6.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/7.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/8.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/9.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/10.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/11.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/12.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/13.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/14.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/15.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/16.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/146-madison/17.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="button prevButton"></span>
    <span class="button nextButton"></span>
    </div>  

    <br />
    <br />
    <hr class="purple">
    <br />


    <!-- TITLE AREA -->
    <article>
    <section>
    <div class="lefttextbig">
        <header>
        <h1 class="black">Edwardian Mansion in the Annex</h1>
        <br />
        <h2 class="black">146 Madison Ave.</h2>
        </header>
        <p class="black">
            <br />
            <span class="subtitle">GRAND PROPORTIONS</span> A spectacular juxtaposition of rich woodwork, bay windows and fireplaces with modern luxurious appointments and updates. The chef's kitchen features a solid stainless steel counter and professional appliances (Wolf 6-burner stove with griddle and Subzero fridge).
            <br /><br />

            <span class="subtitle">HANDLED WITH CARE</span> This centennial home has been fully restored and renovated over the previous decade and has been lovingly maintained. All systems have been updated, including the electrical, plumbing, new SpacePak air conditioning and an efficient boiler.
            <br /><br />


            <span class="subtitle">AMPLE ROOM TO SPARE</span> Includes five bedrooms and office space upstairs. The finished basement apartment has two walkouts. Fully landscaped front and rear gardens.
            <br /><br />
            To inquire further about this property please <a href="../contact/index.php" class="black">contact Boris</a>.
        </p>
    </div>
    </section>
    <!--TITLE AREA-->
    <section>
     <div class="rightinfo">

                <a href="approach/index.php" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    <div class="purpleb round formstyle bgcolor sendform" style="
                    padding: 15px 15px 8px 15px;
                    width: 210px;
                    text-align: center;">
                        <span class="parastyle black" style="font-weight: normal;
                        letter-spacing: 0.1em;">
                            BOOK A SHOWING
                        </span>

                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="approach/index.php" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    <div class="purpleb round formstyle bgcolor sendform" style="
                    padding: 15px 15px 8px 15px;
                    width: 210px;
                    text-align: center;">
                        <span class="parastyle black" style="font-weight: normal;
                        letter-spacing: 0.1em;">
                            VIEW FLOORPLAN
                        </span>

                    </div>
                </a>
                <hr class="purple">
                <p>
                    <span class="subtitle">Price:</span>
                    $2,295,000
                </p>

                <hr class="purple">
                <p>
                    <span class="subtitle">Open House Times:</span><br />
                    Sat 21<sup>st</sup> / 2:30pm&#8211;4:30pm<br />
                    Sun 22<sup>nd</sup> / 3pm&#8211;5pm

                </p>

                <hr class="purple">
                <p>
                    <span class="subtitle">Book a Showing:</span><br /> <a href="146-madison-book.php" class="black">Request a Time</a>

                </p>

                <hr class="purple">




                <hr class="purple">
                <p class="small">

                    <span class="italic">Layout:</span>
                    <a href="images/146-madison/146-madison-floorplan-boris.pdf" class="black">Floorplan</a>
                </p>


                <hr class="purple">
                <p class="small">
                    <span class="italic">Type:</span>
                    3-Story, Brick Detached
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Neighbourhood:</span>
                    The Annex
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Rooms:</span>
                    12 + 4
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Bedrooms:</span>
                    5 + 1
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Washrooms:</span>
                    5
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Parking:</span>
                    1 Front Yard Spot <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (Not Legalized)<br />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Street Permits Availavble
                </p>

                <hr class="purple">
                <p class="small">
                    <span class="italic">Living:</span>
                    <!--1-->12ft<!--1-->&#215;<!--2-->19ft<!--2-->
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Dining:</span>
                    <!--1-->12ft<!--1-->&#215;<!--2-->20ft<!--2-->
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Kitchen:</span>
                    <!--1-->24ft<!--1-->&#215;<!--2-->17ft<!--2-->
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Master:</span>
                    <!--1-->12ft<!--1-->&#215;<!--2-->17ft<!--2-->
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Other:</span>
                    <!--1-->9ft<!--1-->&#215;<!--2-->9ft<!--2-->
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">2<sup>nd</sup> Br:</span>
                    <!--1-->11ft<!--1-->&#215;<!--2-->14ft<!--2-->
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">3<sup>rd</sup> Br:</span>
                    <!--1-->12ft<!--1-->&#215;<!--2-->18ft<!--2-->
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">4<sup>th</sup> Br:</span>
                    <!--1-->13ft<!--1-->&#215;<!--2-->11ft<!--2-->
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">5<sup>th</sup> Br:</span>
                    <!--1-->16ft<!--1-->&#215;<!--2-->11ft<!--2-->
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Bsmnt Office:</span>
                    <!--1-->11ft<!--1-->&#215;<!--2-->12ft<!--2-->
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Bsmnt Br:</span>
                    <!--1-->11ft<!--1-->&#215;<!--2-->17ft<!--2-->
                    <br />


                </p>

                    <hr class="purple">
                <p class="small">
                    To inquire further about this property please <a href="../contact/index.php" class="black">contact Boris</a>.
                </p>

            </div>
      </section>
    </article>

<?php include('../footer.html');?> 


</div>
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->


<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(window).load(function(){
        var pages = $('#container li'), current=0;
        var currentPage,nextPage;
        var timeoutID;
        var buttonClicked=0;

        var handler1=function(){
            buttonClicked=1;
            $('#container .button').unbind('click');
            currentPage= pages.eq(current);
            if($(this).hasClass('prevButton'))
            {
                if (current <= 0)
                    current=pages.length-1;
                    else
                    current=current-1;
            }
            else
            {

                if (current >= pages.length-1)
                    current=0;
                else
                    current=current+1;
            }
            nextPage = pages.eq(current);   
            currentPage.fadeTo('slow',0.3,function(){
                nextPage.fadeIn('slow',function(){
                    nextPage.css("opacity",1);
                    currentPage.hide();
                    currentPage.css("opacity",1);
                    $('#container .button').bind('click',handler1);
                }); 
            });         
        }

        var handler2=function(){
            if (buttonClicked==0)
            {
            $('#container .button').unbind('click');
            currentPage= pages.eq(current);
            if (current >= pages.length-1)
                current=0;
            else
                current=current+1;
            nextPage = pages.eq(current);   
            currentPage.fadeTo('slow',0.3,function(){
                nextPage.fadeIn('slow',function(){
                    nextPage.css("opacity",1);
                    currentPage.hide();
                    currentPage.css("opacity",1);
                    $('#container .button').bind('click',handler1);             
                }); 
            });
            timeoutID=setTimeout(function(){
                handler2(); 
            }, 8000);
            }
        }

        $('#container .button').click(function(){
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
            handler1();
        });

        timeoutID=setTimeout(function(){
            handler2(); 
            }, 8000);

});

</script>
<!-- Larger Retina Image Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../retina.js"></script>
<!-- Larger Retina Image Script -->



</body>
</html>
```

CSS (Some Details omitted due to space limitations):

```
/* FONTS */

@import url("http://fast.fonts.net/t/1.css?apiType=css&projectid=5d4e4047-c57e-412e-b5ff-25df646ca2cd");
@font-face{
font-family:"Bodoni MT W01 Book";
src:url("Fonts/4e3cd7ee-0719-4362-b87b-7f12a33dce14.eot?#iefix");
src:url("Fonts/4e3cd7ee-0719-4362-b87b-7f12a33dce14.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),url("Fonts/d7f7fba3-4873-4084-b7f2-6f3fa4ee6019.woff") format("woff"),url("Fonts/3d829673-d42c-49ec-8799-1287be541432.ttf") format("truetype"),url("Fonts/03aed8dc-9240-455c-9c8b-2af3002590e9.svg#03aed8dc-9240-455c-9c8b-2af3002590e9") format("svg");
}
@font-face{
font-family:"BodoniMTW01-BookItalic";
src:url("Fonts/c5b77b15-773a-4eb4-976a-49da92e5829d.eot?#iefix");
src:url("Fonts/c5b77b15-773a-4eb4-976a-49da92e5829d.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),url("Fonts/fef20495-bab9-40eb-a873-7791998e1f4f.woff") format("woff"),url("Fonts/e005478c-7941-4de3-bd68-040d7d07645e.ttf") format("truetype"),url("Fonts/e74f7fa9-a29a-40e0-85ea-653bff2f2002.svg#e74f7fa9-a29a-40e0-85ea-653bff2f2002") format("svg");
}
@font-face{
font-family:"Bodoni MT W01 Bold";
src:url("Fonts/ad42559d-c219-4fda-bd8e-c85aebe62e62.eot?#iefix");
src:url("Fonts/ad42559d-c219-4fda-bd8e-c85aebe62e62.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),url("Fonts/6a76c8c6-2abe-4842-b3e2-e675c21ddd49.woff") format("woff"),url("Fonts/aaf1ac29-cd40-43ec-9a28-a947df44d661.ttf") format("truetype"),url("Fonts/cf4a1397-b8a7-47e5-981d-acab77e93efc.svg#cf4a1397-b8a7-47e5-981d-acab77e93efc") format("svg");
}
@font-face{
font-family:"BodoniMTW01-BoldItalic";
src:url("Fonts/e13cc406-81c1-4488-98f4-9681fcd4ad90.eot?#iefix");
src:url("Fonts/e13cc406-81c1-4488-98f4-9681fcd4ad90.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),url("Fonts/70d2660b-742e-42fd-8a76-4bcb1c2f9b40.woff") format("woff"),url("Fonts/942ebb33-f273-4c9f-bfce-f12b16fc03e0.ttf") format("truetype"),url("Fonts/744ea55c-40b6-48d2-93f4-5d1d056ca8fa.svg#744ea55c-40b6-48d2-93f4-5d1d056ca8fa") format("svg");
}
@font-face{
font-family:"DIN Next W01 Light";
src:url("Fonts/3e0b2cd7-9657-438b-b4af-e04122e8f1f7.eot?#iefix");
src:url("Fonts/3e0b2cd7-9657-438b-b4af-e04122e8f1f7.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),url("Fonts/bc176270-17fa-4c78-a343-9fe52824e501.woff") format("woff"),url("Fonts/3516f91d-ac48-42cd-acfe-1be691152cc4.ttf") format("truetype"),url("Fonts/d1b1e866-a411-42ba-8f75-72bf28e23694.svg#d1b1e866-a411-42ba-8f75-72bf28e23694") format("svg");
}
@font-face{
font-family:"DINNextW01-LightItalic";
src:url("Fonts/3ab2ca1d-35c8-4471-9c57-04cb66b9cffa.eot?#iefix");
src:url("Fonts/3ab2ca1d-35c8-4471-9c57-04cb66b9cffa.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),url("Fonts/e1c997f3-fb27-4289-abc6-5ef059e51723.woff") format("woff"),url("Fonts/0b3b140c-bdbe-488f-8976-992b4104de0c.ttf") format("truetype"),url("Fonts/1fdd14a5-aaa2-4662-a7ae-ab0d4c3adb3c.svg#1fdd14a5-aaa2-4662-a7ae-ab0d4c3adb3c") format("svg");
}
@font-face{
font-family:"DIN Next W01 Medium";
src:url("Fonts/324dee78-6585-4c13-8ca3-5817cc600d84.eot?#iefix");
src:url("Fonts/324dee78-6585-4c13-8ca3-5817cc600d84.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),url("Fonts/4bf0ead4-e61b-4992-832b-6ff05828d99f.woff") format("woff"),url("Fonts/73713a0b-8f6a-4c4e-b8a8-7cf238e632f6.ttf") format("truetype"),url("Fonts/b90b6bdf-15e2-4544-9fe0-92c79fff0ecd.svg#b90b6bdf-15e2-4544-9fe0-92c79fff0ecd") format("svg");
}

/* FONTS */




/*COLORS*/
.bgcolor {background-color: #fafbff;
}

.black {color: #141414;
}

a.black:hover {color: #00000
}

.grey {
    color: #888888;}

a.grey:hover {
    color: #000000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
            transition: all 0.3s linear;}


::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
    color: #000000;
    background: #dddae8;
}

::selection {
    color: #000000; 
    background: red
}
/**/
.purpleb{
    border: solid 1px #dddae8;}
/*COLORS END*/




/*FOOTER*/
.footer{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    }



/* HOMEPAGE LINKS */
.mainlinks{
    font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
    }
/* HOMEPAGE LINKS END */




/* MAIN LINKS */
.mainlinks{
    font-family: "BodoniMTW01-BookItalic", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    }
/* MAIN LINKS END */


/*RECO FINEPRINT*/
.reco{
    font-size: 9px; 
    font-family: "DIN Next W01 Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    }
/*RECO FINEPRINT*/


/* LINES */
hr.plain{
    border-style:inset;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    clear:both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    }

hr.purple{
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    color: #dddae8;
    background-color: #dddae8;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    clear:both;
    }
/* LINES */





/* TEXT STYLING */
h1 {
    font-family: "Bodoni MT W01 Book", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 84px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: -.02em;
    margin: 0px;
    }

h2 {
    font-family: "BodoniMTW01-BookItalic", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: -.02em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

.subtitle{
    font-family: "DIN Next W01 Medium", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


    h4 {
    font-family: "DIN Next W01 Medium", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 120px;
    }

p{
    font-family: "DIN Next W01 Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: -.015em;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

.italic{font-family: "DINNextW01-LightItalic", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}

.small {    font-family: "DIN Next W01 Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: -.015em;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

    }



.parastyle{font-family: "DIN Next W01 Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: -.015em;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;    
}

a{padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;}

.footer{
    font-family: "DIN Next W01 Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration:none;}


.reco{
    font-size: 9px; 
    font-family: "DIN Next W01 Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    }

/* TEXT STYLING */





/*BOX SIZING and STYLING*/
div.lefttext{
    width: 665px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }

div.lefttextbig{
    width: 665px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }

div.leftphoto{
    width: 665px;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 105px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }

div.rightblank{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }

div.rightaboutphoto{
    width: 265px;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 35px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }


    div.leftaboutphoto{
    width: 345px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    }


div.rightabouttext{
    width: 620px;
    padding: 0px 0px 60px 0px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    }

div.rightlist{
    width: 238px;
    height: 338px;
    padding: 20px 30px 40px 30px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 105px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px; /* future proofing */
    -khtml-border-radius: 6px; /* for old Konqueror browsers*/
    }

div.rightinfo{
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0px 0px 40px 44px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: solid 1px #dddae8; 
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px; /* future proofing */
    -khtml-border-radius: 6px; /* for old Konqueror browsers*/
    }

div.rightcontactinfo{
    width: 240px;
    padding: 20px 0px 40px 55px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px; /* future proofing */
    -khtml-border-radius: 6px; /* for old Konqueror browsers*/
    }



div.footerl{
    height: 25px; 
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    TEXT-ALIGN: LEFT;
    }

div.footerr{
    height: 25px; 
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    }


div.presscoll{
    width: 235px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
    }

div.presscolm{
    width: 235px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
    }

div.presscolr{
    width: 235px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
    }

img.press{
    width: 233px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    border: solid 1px #E5E5E5;}
/*BOX SIZING and STYLING*/




/* ROUNDED CORNER ON STUFF */
.round{ -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px; /* future proofing */
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px; /* for old Konqueror browsers*/
    }
/* ROUNDED CORNER ON STUFF */


figure{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    }

navigation{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    }

footer{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;}

    #goTop{
    z-index: 100;
    background:red;
    padding:5px;
    position:fixed;
    top:-100px;
    right:10px;
}


/*CONTACT FORM STYLING*/
.formstyle{
    padding: 12px 12px 9px 12px;
    width: 310px;;
    font: bold 0.95em arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    font-family: "DIN Next W01 Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 19px;
    outline: none;
    }

.messagebox{
    width: 631px;
    height: 275px;
    }

.sendform:hover{
    background-color: #dddae8;
    color:#000000;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
 cursor:pointer;
    }

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #CECECE;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #CECECE;  
}
::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #CECECE;  
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #CECECE;  
}

/*CONTACT FORM STYLING*/


/*SLIDE STYLING*/

#container{
        width:1000px;
        height:550px;
        position:relative;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;

    }

    #container ul{
        width:1000px;
        height:550px;
        list-style:none outside none;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style:none;
    }


    #container li:first-child{
        display:list-item;
        position:absolute;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #container li{
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }


#container .prevButton{
        height:72px;
        width:68px;
        position:absolute;
        background: url('https://agentboris.com/newwebsite/buttons.png') no-repeat;
        top:515px;
        margin-top:-36px;
        cursor:pointer;
        z-index:2000;
        background-position:left top;
        left:0
    }

    #container .prevButton:hover{ 
            background-position:left bottom;left:0;}



#container .nextButton{
        height:72px;
        width:68px;
        position:absolute;
        background: url('https://agentboris.com/newwebsite/buttons.png') no-repeat;
        top:515px;
        margin-top:-36px;
        cursor:pointer;
        z-index:2000;
        background-position:right top;
        right:0
    }

    #container .nextButton:hover{ 
            background-position:right bottom;right:0;}
/*SLIDE STYLING*/



/** LIGHTBOX MARKUP **/

.lightbox {
    /** Default lightbox to hidden */
    display: none;

    /** Position and style */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;    
    background-color: #fafbff;

}

.lightbox img {
    /** Pad the lightbox image */
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 80%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;
}


.lightbox:target {
    /** Remove default browser outline */
    outline: none;

    /** Unhide lightbox **/
    display: block;
}






/** LIGHTBOX MARKUP **/
```

Comment: I think this was unfairly downvoted. I had a valid problem and I think the downvoter assumed I simply had an incorrect file link; the problem turned out to be more complex than that. See comments in the selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up on the console, it shows that your fonts & your button image are missing.

`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/d7f7fba3-4873-4084-b7f2-6f3fa4ee6019.woff"
d7f7fba...19.woff
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/listings/images/buttons.png"
buttons.png
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/fef20495-bab9-40eb-a873-7791998e1f4f.woff"
fef2049...4f.woff
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/bc176270-17fa-4c78-a343-9fe52824e501.woff"
bc17627...01.woff
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/4bf0ead4-e61b-4992-832b-6ff05828d99f.woff"
4bf0ead...9f.woff
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/6a76c8c6-2abe-4842-b3e2-e675c21ddd49.woff"
6a76c8c...49.woff
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/e1c997f3-fb27-4289-abc6-5ef059e51723.woff"
e1c997f...23.woff
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/3d829673-d42c-49ec-8799-1287be541432.ttf"
3d82967...432.ttf
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/e005478c-7941-4de3-bd68-040d7d07645e.ttf"
e005478...45e.ttf
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/3516f91d-ac48-42cd-acfe-1be691152cc4.ttf"
3516f91...cc4.ttf
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/73713a0b-8f6a-4c4e-b8a8-7cf238e632f6.ttf"
73713a0...2f6.ttf
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/aaf1ac29-cd40-43ec-9a28-a947df44d661.ttf"
aaf1ac2...661.ttf
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/0b3b140c-bdbe-488f-8976-992b4104de0c.ttf"
0b3b140...e0c.ttf
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/d7f7fba3-4873-4084-b7f2-6f3fa4ee6019.woff"
d7f7fba...19.woff
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/fef20495-bab9-40eb-a873-7791998e1f4f.woff"
fef2049...4f.woff
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/bc176270-17fa-4c78-a343-9fe52824e501.woff"
bc17627...01.woff
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/4bf0ead4-e61b-4992-832b-6ff05828d99f.woff"
4bf0ead...9f.woff
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/e1c997f3-fb27-4289-abc6-5ef059e51723.woff"
e1c997f...23.woff
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/6a76c8c6-2abe-4842-b3e2-e675c21ddd49.woff"
6a76c8c...49.woff
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/3d829673-d42c-49ec-8799-1287be541432.ttf"
3d82967...432.ttf
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/e005478c-7941-4de3-bd68-040d7d07645e.ttf"
e005478...45e.ttf
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/73713a0b-8f6a-4c4e-b8a8-7cf238e632f6.ttf"
73713a0...2f6.ttf
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/aaf1ac29-cd40-43ec-9a28-a947df44d661.ttf"
aaf1ac2...661.ttf
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/3516f91d-ac48-42cd-acfe-1be691152cc4.ttf"
3516f91...cc4.ttf
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/0b3b140c-bdbe-488f-8976-992b4104de0c.ttf"
0b3b140...e0c.ttf`

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that before. The fonts are indeed linked correctly in the code, but when implemented on the server those links change for some reason, pointing to directories that don't exist.

http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/Fonts/0b3b140c-bdbe-488f-8976-992b4104de0c.ttf >> Should be >> http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/Fonts/0b3b140c-bdbe-488f-8976-992b4104de0c.ttf

http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/listings/listings/images/buttons.png >> should be >> http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/buttons.png

Comment: Its not linking properly. Your fonts are not in the listing folder. The correct path is http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/Fonts/e005478c-7941-4de3-bd68-040d7d07645e.ttf. Check your design.css, it should be url("../Fonts/") instead of just url("Font/")

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. However, the fonts are linked correctly in my html file, but _something is changing them when I load it to the server (or when the page loads in a browser)_. The Font folder is in the same folder as design.css. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You have two design.css, the one with correct path gets overwrite. See your source page.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize that! How come there are two? I tried to replace the old one.

Comment: I guess your <?php include('../navigation.html');?>  has a style sheet in it. You already defined one in the header.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thanks for the tip. I'll try that out tomorrow.

Comment: Awesome! So far it works great, all the error messages are gone! Thanks a lot.